# How to push the div next to the end of row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="next-to-div"></div>
</div>
```

I want to place `div.next-to-div` just next to `div.col-md-4`. If I use this markup, then obviously it will place that div to a new line. Please help!

Comment: you will need to put the `<div class="next-to-div"></div>` directly beneath `<div class="col-md-4"></div>`

Comment: @hans-könig the OP might just want to take up a third of the page

Answer (score 1):

Place your div.next-to-div in div.row

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="next-to-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't place div next to the column. Will it be possible to do this in the way I want?

Comment: If you mean an other order on mobile, you can add order-* classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the container `d-flex` and use `justify-content-between` to separate the divs...

```
<div class="wrapper container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next-to-div">next dov</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/F3r1GeXCoF